# Can entry into US just before visa expires create any problems?

Tags: visas, usa, regulations, customs-and-immigration

My mother's visa is expiring soon. I am intending to take her to USA on a one month trip but I am fearful, her entry into USA when her visa is expiring that soon may cause problems?

Note that I have done that before, she last entered USA when her visa was expiring in about 20 days. She then got another 5 year multiple visa, but now that visa is expiring soon too.

My concern is, would it be ok for my mother to enter USA just 3 days before her visa expires. She will have a return ticket.

Comment: Wait, so she will enter the USA 3 days before her visa expires, **and she'll be staying longer than 3 days**.  So she will still be in the USA after her visa expires.  Is that correct?

Comment: Harper that is perfectly alright for USA.

Comment: @Harper yes, that part I know is fine. Have done that before :) Just the entry in the last days I am not sure about.

Comment: It is perfectly okay, however what precludes you from getting a new one? I ask because I know of people who got grilled for entering on the last few days of their passport. Immigration officials can be unreasonable.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen That's passport, not visa. They are different.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen First this visa is getting 5 years old and we still did not use it. 2nd it is like test run for my mother, if she likes it there, can then apply for 2nd one, 3rd I got a bit of break so I can take her now. Also new visa is not guaranteed :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton I made a typo, I meant visa. know the difference. Most country citizens cannot even enter the USA with passport less than 6 months validity. That’s a different animal. I am specifically referring to visas close to expiry.

Comment: Understood @CuriousTraveler.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen US visas don't work that way, though. The validity date is for entry only; you can still remain in the country for six months or whatever even if you enter on the last day of visa validity, and people do this all the time. It's not a big deal.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know the rules better than most, trust me. I’ve had about nine or more USA visas in my journey from visitor to student through H1B in addition to scrupulously reading up on immigration practices. I am telling him what has actually happened. Practice as you know is sometimes different than theory, especially for visitors from developing nations and particularly Africa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

She can enter even on the day it expires. US visas are for entry requests only and it is not a problem to use them on their last date.

Just for the sake of completion, she can then stay in the US for as long as the CBP stamp/record allows. Even beyond the expiry date of her visa.

> **What the Visa Expiration Date Means**
>
> The visa expiration date is shown on the visa along with the visa issuance date. The time between visa issuance and expiration date is called your visa validity. The visa validity is the length of time you are permitted to travel to a port-of-entry in the United States.

Source: [travel.state.gov](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-expiration-date.html)

Comment: For the record, We arrived in US on 15 noon-time, Mom visas was expiring on 17. Immigration was a breeze, no issue at all, no questions. Mom got 6 month extension in stay. Really happy. Thanks for the answer.